# ios continuously check to see if request succeeds

Tags: ios, offline, nsthread

I have a concept of an `offline mode` in my app. Whenever a request fails due to connectivity issues, or a 500 response from my server, I automatically put my app into `offline mode`. I then save the `request` which triggered the offline mode, and in the next successful request I make, I re-run the original request that failed. If the request succeeds this time, I take the application out of `offline mode`.

The issue with this mechanism is that it requires the user to perform an action to trigger a successful api call that subsequently then re-sends the original request. I want to know the best way I can continuously send the request on its own thread and listen for a successful response.

I am fairly new to ios development so looking to be pointed towards some best practices around this scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't. Search for iOS reachability and use the observer to trigger retries.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, ios reachability is only notified when the reachability status changes (i.e. network connectivity becomes unreachable or reachable). I am trying to protect against the scenario where my server is not responding correctly for some reason as well.

Comment: The correct approach is not to continuously drain the battery and use up the data plan. If you get a bad response and reachability says the network is still available then maybe use a timer and try again in a minute

Comment: What does reachability do such that it doesn't drain the battery / data plan? Also a one minute timer?

Comment: It uses the signals that the phone is sending anyway to determine reachability. Yes, once per minute if your server is having issues may be acceptable - continuously is not acceptable

Comment: How does the reachability plug into the signals given the fact that I can provide any custom hostname when checking for reachability? i.e. `Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.randomhostname.com"];`

I am asking because I was hoping I could use the same mechanism reachability uses for my purposes, but given the way you explained it, seems like that might not be possible.

Comment: I find that `reachabilityWithHostname:` doesn't usually offer great accuracy as it doesn't actually send data to the host, it just verifies the existence of a potential route to the host...

Comment: Got it -- I think I will just go ahead and stick with my current method of re-checking anytime another api call is successfully made, combined with hooking into reachability for protecting against connectivity issues. Thanks for all the help!